# Image type field in Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm

In Sugar CRM , want to upload the images but there is no such type of field. How to create image type field in Sugar CRM as this field is already in Sugar CRM Professional edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link

It will solve your big problem

https://www.atcoresystems.com/blog/adding-a-photo-to-a-contact-record

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension SugarForge: Photo field by SYNOLIA: Project Info

Comment: hello mahi.. which version of sugar crm you are using?

Comment: I have tried it in sugar 6.2.6.. it create type of photo but when in edit layout is shows images cannot processed